# can not login to my site using user model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I created user model using BaseUserManager and AbstractBaseUser. admin can be craeted and login successfully. but when i add a non-admin user i cant use it to login my site. 
so, superuser can login. others are created successfully but can not login. i do not know where is the problem. that is the code(models.py):

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
from django.db import models


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email,  name = "anynomous", password=None ):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('enter your email')

        user = self.model(
            email=MyUserManager.normalize_email(email),
            name = name,
        )
        user = self.create_user(email,
                                password=password,
                                name= name,
                                )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_superuser = False
        user.is_admin = False
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(email,
                                password=password,
                                )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user





class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, db_index=True , null=False , blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50 , null=True, blank=True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    def create_user(self, email,  name = "anynomous", password=None ):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('enter your email')

        user = self.model(
            email=MyUserManager.normalize_email(email),
            name = name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.is_superuser = False

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user



    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

Comment: Where do you try to login? /admin?

Comment: Does the user actually exist in your user model?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` in your project's settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
]
```

and also as you already overwrite Django's User Model you need to mention User Model location in your settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'YOUR_User_MODEL_LOCATION'
```